# Pointers as parameters in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm new to C++, coming from mostly working with Java and I'm having a problem with a function I'm trying to write. I'm sure it's something simple, but nonetheless, it's giving me fits, so prepare for a painfully newbie question.

I'm trying to write a function as follows:

```
void foo(u_char *ct){

/* ct is a counter variable, 
it must be written this way due to the library 
I need to use keeping it as an arbitrary user argument*/

/*here I would just like to convert the u_char to an int, 
print and increment it for each call to foo, 
the code sample I'm working from attempts to do it more or less as follows:*/

int *counter = (int *) ct;
printf("Count: %d\n", *counter);
*counter++;

return;

}
```

When I try to run this in XCode (something I'm also new to using), I get a EXE_BAD_ACCESS exception on the printf() portion of foo. I'm really not sure what is going on here but I suspect that it has something to do with conflating values, pointers and references, something I don't yet have a strong gasp of how C++ understands them coming from Java. Does anyone see where I'm slipping up here?

Thanks.

Comment: what is sizeof(u_char) versus sizeof(int)?

Comment: @KevinHsu they both return 8.

Comment: Integral type means a builtin type that has a discrete integer representation. For example, `int`, `short`, `bool`, `char` are all considered integral types as well as pointers and typedef alias of them.

Comment: Not sure how `sizeof` is helping us here. All we can infer from it is that this is probably on a 64-bit environment.

Comment: It is a 64 bit machine, yes.

Comment: Can you provide some context on how `foo` is being used? Is this is a callback function that the library calls or do you call it from other parts of your code? What does `u_char *ct` actually point to? What assumptions are being made about the data being pointed to?

Comment: @greatwolf see Shimodax's answer, *ct points to an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT (based on comments down here where poster says it's called actually with the address of an int:  `foo((u_char*)&count)` ):

```
void foo(u_char *ct)
{
   int *pcounter = (int *)ct;  // change pointer back to an int *
   printf("Count: %d\n", *pcounter);
   (*pcounter)++;  // <<-- brackets here because of operator precedence.
}
```

Or even shorter (the wild c-style for which everbody but newbies loves this language):

```
void foo(u_char *ct)
{
   printf("Count: %d\n", (*(int *)ct)++);
}
```

Comment: `the wild c-style for which everbody but newbies loves this language` so if you prefer C++ casts over C casts in C++, you're a newbie?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yeah pretty green here.

Comment: @Lucjian: I'm sure a C++ programmer like you can decipher and even correctly invert logical expressions in natural language too.

Comment: @Shimodax I'm still getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS here in XCode (at: int counter = *ct;). Is this possibly just a problem with XCode?

Comment: @Bobby.  If that happens, the ct pointer points to something that is not accessible memory.  This will be a problem in the place where foo() is called.  If you make a program part like this: void boo() { u_char x=0; foo(&x); foo(&x); foo(&x); }  it will work.

Comment: @Shimodax I don't know if this helps you out but the ct being passed to foo is originally an int but is cast as follows in the call: (u_char *) ct.

Comment: @Bobby: Oh, that changes everything.  Can you change the call?  Because it should be (probably) 'foo ( (u_char *) &ct );' and then your original code would be correct, except the missing brackets (*counter)++;

Answer (score 4):

An `u_char` would be 1 byte in memory (the name suggests it's just an unsigned char), an `int` is typically 4 bytes. In `printf`, you tell the runtime to read an `int` (4 bytes) from the address where `counter` resides. But you only own 1 byte there.

Comment: okay, how do I resolve this? Because I ultimately need it to be an int.

Comment: @BobbyGryzynger have you tried `int counter = static_cast<int>(*ct);`.

Comment: `int counter = static_cast<int>(*ct);`, `printf("Count: %d\n", counter)` and `(*ct)++;`. Since you're coming from a Java background, do note that here, to the hardware, other than the size, there is no difference between an int, a char, a bool, a long or a short.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I still get the EXE_BAD_ACCESS exception with int counter = static_cast<int>(*ct);

Comment: @BobbyGryzynger does `ct` point to a string literal by any chance?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore it's being cast like this coming in: (u_char *) ct. It starts as an int itself, but like I said in the original question, it must be a u_char in the library I need this for.